# Getting Transaction ID from Authorize.Net CIM API

Tags: api, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am creating a CIM API for authorize.net. I have it all working perfectly, but I need the transaction id to be returned to me when a transaction is created.

Right now, this what I have being returned when I complete a transaction:

```
if ($cim->isSuccessful())
    {
        $approval_code = $cim->getAuthCode();


    }


    // Print the results of the request
    echo '<strong>Request Response Summary:</strong> ' .
                               $cim->getResponseSummary() . '';
    echo '<strong>Approval code:</strong> ' . $approval_code;
```

Then this is the output I get: Request Response Summary: Response code: I00001 Message: Successful.Approval code: NXD8X7

No transaction ID is returned. I want to know how I can go about getting this. My goal is to write this to my database, but I need some way to get the transaction id. Thank you very much.

Comment: Figured it out, just wasn't returning the right value.

$trans_id = $cim->getTransactionID();

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AuthorizeNet SDK you can get all response fields as an object with calling $response->getTransactionResponse  function like following.

```
    $request = new AuthorizeNetCIM();
    $response = $request->createCustomerProfileTransaction('AuthCapture', $transaction);
    $transactionResponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
    $transactionResponse->transaction_id
```